# Objective C: I'm trying to save an NSDictionary that contains primitives and object, but error occurred once i tried adding the custom object

Tags: objective-c, encoding, save, nsdictionary, nscoding

So I have this custom object i made called 'Box', it's throwing the error for that one.
Inside of my NSDictionary is...

```
box = [[Box alloc] initWithHeight:20 height:40];    
wrap.dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:numberInt, kInt, numberShort, kShort, numberLong, kLong, numberFloat, kFloat, numberDouble, kDouble, numberBool, kBool, nsString, kString, nsDate, kDate, box, @"keybox", nil];
```

Notice the box object that I created up top and added in the NSDictionary at the very end. Before when the box wasn't in there, everything worked fine, but when I added the custom object 'Box', it couldn't save anymore.

```
- (void) saveDataToDisk:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryForDisk 
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    //Encode 
    [archiver setOutputFormat:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0];
    [archiver encodeObject:dictionaryForDisk forKey:@"Dictionary_Key"];

    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self pathForDataFile] atomically:YES];
}

- (NSString *) pathForDataFile {
    NSArray*    documentDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* path = nil;
    if (documentDir) 
    {
        path = [documentDir objectAtIndex:0];    
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path, @"data.bin"];
}
```

This was the error

```
-[Box encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e30d60
2011-11-11 11:56:43.430 nike[1186:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Box encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e30d60'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Is your BOX class conforming to NSCoding protocol (with support for keyed-archiving)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception tells you that it's trying to send `-encodeWithCoder:` to your `Box` instance. If you look up the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000294-BAJJGGCE), you can see that this belongs to the [`NSCoding`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. `NSCoding` is used by `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode objects. `NSDictionary`'s implementation of `NSCoding` requires that all keys and objects inside it also conform to `NSCoding`. In your case, all the previous values stored in your dictionary conform to `NSCoding`, but your `Box` instance doesn't.

You need to implement `-initWithCoder:` and `-encodeWithCoder:` on your `Box` class and then declare that your class conforms to `NSCoding` by modifying the declaration to look like

```
@interface Box : Superclass <NSCoding>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your custom Box class must adhere to the `NSCoding` Protocol. The protocol documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Ray Wenderlich has a good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager).