# How to store/retrieve NSDictionary into NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

in my app I have no problem withs saving/retrieving string values(like `myTextField.text`) into `NSUserDefaults` but whatever i do to store `NSDictionary` i coldn't succeed. And i tried a lot of answer from this site+ Google. Can anyone please help? Here is my code too:

```
id result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
               NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);


      NSDictionary *dict= [result objectForKey:@"message"];
    //i want to store dict sub dictionary
```

**EDIT**Note:The dictionary contains a kind of array of objects, and the objects are all members of property list(NSString, NSDate, ...)

Comment: Why can't you succeed? Is there an error?

Comment: @JoePasq no, no error. When i try to retrieve data it just returns Null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the other answers are trying to tell you is, you have to get rid of your (id). NSUserDefaults and the compiler will complain and throw warnings if you try and put an id into the user defaults. Try it out this way.

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if (result) {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:result forKey:@"yourUniqueKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because some of the objects in your `NSDictionary` are not Objective C primitive objects, or to put it a better way, iOS doesn't know how to convert the custom data in the `NSDictionary` to a form that can be saved and loaded again.

So you need to learn how to get those custom objects to conform to `NSCoding`.

[Here is a related question that should have some useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099240/objective-c-im-trying-to-save-an-nsdictionary-that-contains-primitives-and-obj) for you.

Comment: The dictionary contains a kind of array of objects, and the objects are all members of property list(NSString, NSDate, ...)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are storing. Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says

> The `NSUserDefaults` class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of `NSData`. For more details, see [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i).

I assume you are trying to store a type other than the listed ones.

Comment: What type is `result`? I bet that because it is type `id` NSUserDefaults is balking at storing it *even though* it really is a valid type.

Comment: please see my edit. result itself is a NSDictionary, and contains NString and NSDate

Comment: Please see my earlier comment on my answer. :)